# Writing test code for trigger on Master/Detail

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I managed to get a simple rollup working fine for a rollup. The next step is to write a test for it.

```
trigger doRollup on Daily_Time_Record__c (after insert, after update, after delete, after   undelete) {

// List of parent record ids to update
  Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();

// In-memory copy of parent records
Map<Id,Time_Record__c> parentRecords = new Map<Id,Time_Record__c>();

// Gather the list of ID values to query on
for(Daily_Time_Record__c c:Trigger.isDelete?Trigger.old:Trigger.new)
  parentIds.add(c.Time_Record_Link__c);

// Avoid null ID values
parentIds.remove(null);

// Create in-memory copy of parents
for(Id parentId:parentIds)
parentRecords.put(parentId,new Time_Record__c(Id=parentId,RollupTarget__c=0));

// Query all children for all parents, update Rollup Field value
for(Daily_Time_Record__c c:[select id,FieldToRoll__c,Time_Record_Link__c from   Daily_Time_Record__c where Time_Record_Link__c in :parentIds])
  parentRecords.get(c.Time_Record_Link__c).RollupTarget__c += c.FieldToRoll__c;


// Commit changes to the database

Database.update(parentRecords.values());
}
```

Is the code. Straightforward.

Having never written a test before, I started sifting around for what to do. From what I read, I need to make a scenario that kicks off the trigger to test it. So my assumption was that I needed to essentially make a child record. I thought I'd start small and work my way up, but instantly hit an issue:

```
@isTest
private class TestTriggerRollUp
  { 
    //
    // This testMethod tests trigger Dailt Time
    // 
    public static testmethod void testRollUp()
        {
    //Create a new instance of Daily Time with test values 
             Daily_Time_Record__c dtr = new Daily_Time_Record__c(Name = 'DAY-00000');

            //Insert the object virtually
            insert dtr;
    }
}
```

Now apparently this is due to the Master/Detail relationship. I am not entirely sure where to go next. Sifting around the net gives me people who have reams of example code and it is rather difficult for a newbie to pick to pieces.

So, anyone got any help?

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that your test data is not setup fully. By default, test classes cannot see the data in your org so you must create all of the necessary test data. For a master-detail relationship that means you will first need to create and insert the master record and then create and insert a child record for it.

For example, using `Person Accounts` and `Opportunities`:

```
Account testAccount = new Account(
        FirstName = 'first', 
        LastName = 'Last',
        RecordTypeId = myPersonAccountRecordTypeId);    
insert testAccount;

Opportunity testOpp = new Opportunity(
        Name = 'test opportunity'
        AccountId = testAccount.Id,
        CloseDate = System.Today(),
        StageName = 'Prospecting'
);    
insert testOpp;
```

This would now give me a test Account and Opportunity to work with. You will need to mimic this for your data model as necessary and set the field data appropriately.

Comment: Ok so look at my two custom objects and set them up with their appropriate data (at least the mandatory items I need).

I can have a go at that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also put the following on the top line of your test class. This will let the class see your salesforce data.

@isTest(SeeAllData=true)

Note: your test may fail when you move to production because the test is probably different, so it's better to create all data needed for the test as previously stated in another answer.

Cheers